# Handling multiple CircleCI workflows with a shared jobs

Tags: circleci

How can I trigger some job that requires another job in another CircleCI workflow in the same project?

For example:

```yaml
workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - build:
          name: "build docker image"
          <<: *circleci_contexts
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /.*/

  test:
    jobs:
      - test_a:
          <<: *circleci_contexts
          requires:
            - "build docker image"
```

The job `test_a` should execute only when the job "build docker image" from the first workflow will be done.